# how to configure response to send to client upon logging in using facebook oauth strategy with passport

Tags: javascript, facebook, express, oauth, passport-facebook

This thread addresses what I would like to do to a degree [What is function User.findOrCreate doing and when is it called in passport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431049/what-is-function-user-findorcreate-doing-and-when-is-it-called-in-passport) , but does not address how what the final callback (done) is doing.  I wasn't able to pick up on how this callback relates back to the response given to the client either in this thread nor in the official documentation for passport-facebook here https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook .  It almost seems as if the done callback should eventually lead to one of two paths in the example in the other thread:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

-redirect to /login
-redirect to /

neither of these two happen, but instead I get sent the user information passed in done.  Also, on the client side, I'm making the get request through an anchor tag as described here: [CORS - Facebook - Passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002777/cors-facebook-passport).

Edit with code as requested below:

I also reviewed passport's official documentation and saw that it advises to pass null as the first argument for success cases, which I did and that resolved the above mentioned issue to a degree. I'm still struggling with getting the user information retrieved to the client and was wondering if that information is sent when redirected.  It's a bit puzzling since I am initiating this through the user clicking an anchor element which eliminates the usual handling of received data through callbacks were I to use an ajax request.

My strategy code is as follows:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: '#################',
  clientSecret: '######################',
  callbackURL: '/auth/facebook/callback',
  profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'email'],
  enableProof: true
}, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
  db.checkUserByFb([profile.id], data => {
    // not found, failure case
    if(data.length === 0) {
      db.createFbUser([profile.displayName, profile.id], data => {
        console.log('new user made!: ', data);
        db.checkUserByFb([data.insertId], data => {
          console.log('user made!: ', data);
          console.log(cb);
          cb(null, data);
        });
      });
    // success case
    } else {
      console.log('user found!: ', data[0].name);
      return cb(null, data[0].name);
    }
  });
}));

app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {authType: 'rerequest', scope: ['user_friends', 'manage_pages', 'public_profile', 'email']}));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
        passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/logIn' }),
        function(req, res) {
          console.log('request from fb: ', res.body);
          res.redirect('/userhome');
        });
```

Comment: Post your strategy code please

Comment: And to answer your questions about the callback done Passport uses, that is used solely for you to create a user object/or find one based on the profile returned then you call done with that so it may be serialized and sessioned!

Comment: Probably shouldn't include your API keys publicly